# prepend HTML for sibling element according to their attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have HTML like this:

```
<a attr="A" class="a1">Alabama</a>
<a attr="A" class="a1">Alaska</a>
<a attr="A" class="a1">Arkansas</a>

<a attr="C" class="a1">California</a>
<a attr="C" class="a1">Colorado</a>
<a attr="C" class="a1">Connecticut</a>

<a attr="N" class="a1">Nevada</a>
<a attr="N" class="a1">New york</a>
<a attr="N" class="a1">North Carolina</a>
```

If the inner text has the same attribute `attr`, prepend it with a tag of `<b>`.
So how can I get following HTML with javascript or jQuery?

```
<b>A</b>
<a attr="A" class="a1">Alabama</a>
<a attr="A" class="a1">Alaska</a>
<a attr="A" class="a1">Arkansas</a>

<b>C</b>
<a attr="C" class="a1">California</a>
<a attr="C" class="a1">Colorado</a>
<a attr="C" class="a1">Connecticut</a>

<b>N</b>
<a attr="N" class="a1">Nevada</a>
<a attr="N" class="a1">New york</a>
<a attr="N" class="a1">North Carolina</a>
```

Comment: You would need to grab the text of each element, place it into an array, sort the array, then iterate the array giving you your desired output.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy the inner text starts with the same letter also has the same attribute `attr`

Comment: why do you use attr ? You are confusing yourself too....

Comment: @C-link it doesnt matter, I can use `value` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var last = '';
$('.a1').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('attr') != last) {
        $(this).before('<b>' + $(this).attr('attr') + '</b>')
        last = $(this).attr('attr');
    }
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6WaH5/)**